# Facebook login via application or webview if app is not installed in Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webview, facebook-c#-sdk

Basically I want to achieve the same fucntionality which you normally see in android or ios devices. So if I click on login it should open facebook application(not webview) if facebook is installed but in case app is not installed it should open webview.

Currently it shows me a message do you want to search on store which I don't want.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Vinod

Comment: Please share your code which you are using.

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Facebook-Login-for-Windows-fd1048f5

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone SDK only has the API to launch an app from another app which wouldn't work in your case since you would not be able to share session tokens.

Your best approach to achieving this would be to try out the third party [Facebook SDK for .NET](http://facebooksdk.net/). Take a look at the [Login API](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/login/) which seems to provide the ability to invoke the facebook application on the app and if not available would take the user to the store (LoginBehaviorApplicationOnly - Windows Phone 8.1).

I understand you would like to bring up the WebView if app isn't available but this SDK doesn't seem to have that functionality. You could contribute to the project or request a feature addition.

Hope this gives you a good start?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but doesn't seem to answer my question. This link I've already downloaded and tested but it doesn't fulfill my requirement. I have requested for a feature on git let's see if they could do this